# Why is it necessary to overfit a yolov2 on a subset of images before model training?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, cnn, object-detection, yolo

I am using yolov2 for passport details detection with 8 classes? My object detectiion bounding boxes has errors though recognition being fine.

I want to know if object_detection by overfitting with a sample subset of training data, say 3 images, helps determine prediction performance? If yes how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, overfit a small sample of training data doesn't help predict performance. Normally, overfit a batch of training data is a debugging method.

It's often very hard to detect logical errors in a neural network. One easy way to test is if our neural network can overfit a small batch of training data, we can reasonably assume that it has no critical bug and start training. The reason is that a neural network can even [fit a random labeling of training data](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.03530.pdf), if it cannot fit a small batch, it's almost guaranteed that there's a bug in your network.

Keep in mind that this is only one test to perform, there might be some other subtle bugs that prevent you from getting a good result.

Comment: So it is a debugging test. And the expected result must and does overfit. This answers my question.